# How does the foreach loop return key and value in the global array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
include 'global.php';
class Config {
    public static function login($path=null){
        if($path){
            $config=$GLOBALS['config'];
            $path=explode('/',$path);

            foreach($path as $bit ) {

                if($config[$bit]){
                    $config=$config[$bit];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and the global array is

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config']=array(
    'mysql'=>array(
        'host'=>'localhost',
        'username'=>'root',
        'password'=>'',
    ),

    'session'=>array(
        'username'=>'user',
        'user_logged'=>'logged_in'
    ),

    'status'=>array(
        'login'=>'true',
    )
);
spl_autoload_register( function($class){
    include 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
});
```

i need to access the elements in global array.but i don't understand how they did it.. can anyone help me out please ? and how can i choose a design pattern  for a web application design?

Comment: Is this someone else's code and you are wondering what it does?  Your question does not make any sense.

Comment: im trying to figure out whats happening with the code

Comment: At least, it is a strange condition `if($config[$bit]){`. Because the values in config array are not boolean, i think you want ask `if(isset($config[$bit]}){`

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an array of global values named $GLOBALS;  This "superglobal" variable is available everywhere without having to declare it.  The code references $GLOBALS['config'] to initialize and to read this value.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

An alternative to using $GLOBALS['config'] within a non-global context (i.e. within a function) is to pull it into scope with the global keyword:

```
public static function login($path=null){
    global $config;

    if($path){    
        $path=explode('/',$path);
        foreach($path as $bit ) {    
            if($config[$bit]){    
                $config=$config[$bit];
            }   
        }
        return $config;
    }

    return false;
}
```